# How can I stop Outlook 2013 pop-up alerts

Tags: microsoft-outlook, imap, gmail-imap, microsoft-outlook-2013

The other day I tried to send an attachment that was too large using my GMail account via Outlook 2013.

Now every couple of minutes I get these popups that say:

> Your IMAP Server wants to Alert you
>   http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=8770

This behavior persists through machine reboots. How can I get this to stop?

Comment: Is the email stuck in the outbox?

Comment: Nope. It's gone. The only thing I tried doing is deleting it from my sent item on from the gmail web interface. Which didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer somewhere and it worked for me.

1. Close outlook
2. Go to /Users/--name--/Documents/Microsoft User Data/Office 2011 Identities/Main Identity/Data Records/Message Attachments/0T/0B/0M/--latest backup
3. Delete the largest latest attachment
4. Open Outlook
5. It will ask you to rebuild the database
6. Say 'OK'
7. takes a minute to rebuild.
8. Reopen Outlook - Problem solved.

Comment: I next time this occurs to me I will check your answer and provide feedback. Unless there is an overwhelming agreement from responses. At which time I will mark as Answer.

Comment: I am on Windows 7 Enterprise and the Microsoft User Data folder does not exist in this location. I searched the entire root and no such folder exists.  OP is asking about Outlook 2013, which is what I have as well.  Seems your solution applies to Outlook 2011 which is fundamentally different.